# How to find highest number from list of strings with python

Tags: list, python-3.6

Im trying to fix my python script that scans for existing anime shows from my disks and then creates a list that has only the most recent episode on it including the shows name.

Then later i use that list to scrape the interwebs to see if new episodes are available for viewing.

For a while now my script has been working but it has run into a problem when the episode number hits 99 or 100 depending how you look at it.

Below is the piece of code i use to group anime shows and get the latest episode number for each show.

below is a show piece of the sorted_list used in the code:

```
sorted_list= [
'Bakumatsu Crisis - 11'
'Bakumatsu Crisis - 12'
'Black Clover - 100'
'Black Clover - 99'
'Black Clover - 98'
'Black Clover - 97'
 ]
```

```py
    latest_list = []
    get_series = itertools.groupby(sorted_list, lambda x: x.split('-')[0])
    find_max = [(series, max(list(episode), key=lambda x: x.split('-'))) for series, episode in get_series]
    for line in find_max:
        latest_list.append(line[1])
    return latest_list
```

The returned "latest_list" looks like this:

```
latest_list= [
'Bakumatsu Crisis - 12'
'Black Clover - 99'
 ]
```

When i expect it to return:

```
 latest_list= [
'Bakumatsu Crisis - 12'
'Black Clover - 100'
 ]
```

I cannot figure this out my self. I have tried sorting the "sorted_list" with python`sorted_list.sort()` but it doesnt do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to split by `' - '`, not `'-'` (because that's what's separating the series name from the episode number in your strings), and, you need to sort by `int(x.split(' - ')[1])`, otherwise it will sort the episode numbers as strings rather than numbers (which is why `'99' > '100'`):

```
get_series = itertools.groupby(sorted_list, lambda x: ' - '.join(x.split(' - ')[:-1]))
find_max = [(series, max(episode, key=lambda x: int(x.split(' - ')[-1]))) for series, episode in get_series]
for line in find_max:
    latest_list.append(line[1])
print(latest_list)
```

Output:

```
['Bakumatsu Crisis - 12', 'Black Clover - 100']
```

However, I suggest that you either use another data structure (such as a dict) or define your own classes to better organize and manipulate your data rather than keeping things messy like this.

Comment: Your suggestion worked, however i then noticed i had some series with addition ' - ' in the name so had to change python [1] to [-1] so it takes the last index as the interger, not the 2nd index  so it became : ```find_max = [(series, max(list(episode), key=lambda x: int(x.split(' - ')[-1]))) for series, episode in get_series]
``` And yes you are right, i should used a dict, however i would have to change ALOT of code futher along in the program for that change, so i rather not do that, atleast for now.

Comment: @Nanoni In that case, you need to also change the group by key to `' - '.join(x.split(' - ')[:-1])`.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here would to stop using a list, and start using a dictionary instead. Dictionaries are more or less json inside of python, and you can assign values to names within it and call those values.
So for this case you should do:

```
anime_dict = {
    'Black Clover' : 100,
    'Bakumatsu Crisis' : 12
    }

sorted_dict = sorted(anime_dict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1])
```

and this would return

```
[('Bakumatsu Crisis', 12), ('Black Clover', 100)]
```

then if you wanted to print them in the way you have them stored here simply do:

```
sorted_dict=dict(sorted_dict) # forgot to mention that prior to this being called, it will be a tuple, my bad
for anime in sorted_dict:
    print(anime, '-', sorted_dict[anime])
```

btw:   back up, gets far of the sky, black rover

Comment: So how would you suggest i go about creating a dict from the filelist? I tried the follwing: python ```sorted_list.update({ep_name: ep_num})``` to the end of the first for loop, but its not working properly, its producing "Black Clover":'99', not "Black Clover":'100'.

Comment: you can just do `sorted_list[ep_name] = ep_num` and that will append it correctly

Comment: Again, 'Black Clover': '99' is returned instead of 100.

Comment: So the function is now a lot cleaner, but it has the exact same issue i had that i came here for, if 100 ep exists, it is not recognized. Heres the code so far ```sorted_dict = {}

    for line in filelist:
        line = line.split()
        ep_num = line[-2]
        ep_string = line[1:-3]
        ep_name = " ".join(str(x) for x in ep_string)
        sorted_dict[ep_name] = ep_num

    sorted_list = []
    for anime in sorted_dict:
        sorted_list.append(anime + ' - ' + sorted_dict[anime])
    return sorted_list```